# Fuse will not go in completely

Tags: dodge, fuse, charger

I just bought an 2012 charger. The drivers headlights went out. Dealership said it is not the bulb but the headlight assembly. Research shows the part is $60-$100. Dealership wants $2000. I on chance looked at the fuse box on the battery. The pink 21 fuse was not input. The fuse was sitting in the fuse box.  It does not fit in the slot. It goes in half way.  It is the right amp 30.  It is rectangular not square. The prongs go in the fuse. Bought a new fuse and the new one does not fit either.  I do not want to force it in. Am I missing something. Did I get the wrong fuse? I do not want to take any other fuses out to see it they are the same for fear that I will not get them in either.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I take it the fuse you're talking about looks more like a small box with a clear top rather than a two pronged bladed fuse?

Comment: Yes rectangular not square.  Prong blades go inside the rectangle